# Rails - Ransack gem - radio buttons settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button, ransack, unselect

I am using Ransack gem in order to create simple search interface. One of the model attributes can be *true* or *false*. So, using the Ransack form builder I have the following code:

```
<div class='radio'>
<%= f.label :is_active_true, 'Is active' %>
<%= f.radio_button :is_active_true, 1, checked: true %>
<%= f.label :is_active_false, 'Is not active' %>
<%= f.radio_button :is_active_false, 1 %>
</div>
```

The problem is I am not able to "unchecked" the radio buttons, once they are checked.

Is there any optios to make the buttons to work or I should use additional JavaScript?

Comment: how did you get it working ? Can you please share the solution. Thanks

Comment: I did not. If I had this working I would post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
<div class='radio'>
<%= f.label :is_active_true, 'Is active' %>
<%= f.radio_button :is_active_true, 1, checked: true %>
<%= f.label :is_active_true, 'Is not active' %>
<%= f.radio_button :is_active_true, 0 %>
</div>
```